# Openflow: Redirect TCP Flow only for Controller

Tags: pox, openflow

i'm new in openflow, i create with mininet a open flow toplogy with 1 controller (POX), one switch, and 3 hosts.

My question is, how can i create one rule in switch to redirect to controller only tcp flow?

*sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dpctl command in mininet (ovs-dpctl in host) to configure flows rules and actions for flows matching the flow rules

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the already provided app l2_learning switch to make it fulfill your needs.

To check if one packet has tcp information:

> tcp_pkt=packet.find('tcp')
>
> > if tcp_pkt is not None:
> >
> > > #do something

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can filter the tcp packets.

1. Using payload attribute of the packet object which coordinating with pox.lib.packet library.
2. Using find() method to find the packets that the type is tcp.

And you can find more information in POX wiki:
[POX Wiki](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-forwarding.l2_learning)

Hope this helpful!